# Discrete Mathematics - Arguments with Quantified Statements

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'd like to know whether my argument proof is sufficient or whether my rule of inference is correct for the following.

```
1. A photographer in ABC tour group has not visited Opera House
2. Every photographer in ABC tour group has visited Botanic Garden
```

Q: Can you conclude that "Someone in ABC tour group has not visited Opera House"?

Argument Proof:

1. Let $T$ be the set of all photographers in ABC tour group.
2. Let $O(t)$ be “$t$ visited Opera House”.
3. Let $B(t)$ be “$t$ visited Botanic Garden”.
4. $\exists t \in T, (\neg O(t)).$ (Premise)
5. $\forall t \in T, (B(t)).$ (Premise)
6. $\exists t \in T, (B(t) → ~O(t)).$ (By Universal Modus Ponens) Q.E.D.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the phrase "A photographer in..." is ambiguous.  It could interpreted as "if you are a photographer in X then Y"....as in "A plumber can fix toilets".  That is a universal quantification.  Or it could be interpreted as "there exists at least one photographer who....", such as in the sentence "A Florida man was found dead last night".  You really have to be careful with these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let X be the set of people in ABC tour group.

Using the first sentence, 
$\exists$x, P(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$ O(x)
Then using existential instantiation,
P(a) $\wedge$ $\sim$ O(a)
Then using specialisation,
$\sim$ O(a)
Finally using existentiation generalisation, you will get the answer.

It seems you do not need the second sentence. Do ask your tutor for clarification.